# Get min from second column if first column is equal in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER Not NULL,
  id1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  id2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  id3 INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0001, 1, 10,100);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0001, 2, 10,100);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0002, 3, 10,100);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0002, 3, 11,100);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0003, 1, 12,101);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0003, 1, 12,102);


-- fetch 
select * from EMPLOYEE where (empId,(id1)) in (SELECT empId,min(id1) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 1=1 group by empId);
```

This query gives me:

```
empId   id1 id2 id3
1   1   10  100
2   3   10  100
2   3   11  100
3   1   12  101
3   1   12  102
```

What I need is:

```
empId   id1 id2 id3
1   1   10  100
2   3   11  100
3   1   12  102
```

So, I am looking for min of id2, if id1 is equal, id3 if both id1 and id2 are equal.
How can I achieve this using a query?

Comment: i am troubling to undestand the logic :  min of id2, if id1 is equal, id3 if both id1 and id2 are equal.

Comment: The logic required is not at all clear. Please explain how you arrived at each row individually.

Comment: The question starts with finding the MIN row associated with id1 (for each employee), then requests (for those rows with matching id1) the min id2 row, but then doesn't mention MIN or MAX of id3 for the case where both id1 and id2 match in corresponding rows.  Clarify that.  In my answer, I assumed all three (id1, id2, id3) where using that MIN logic, in weighted order.  If we want the MAX id3 in those remaining cases, we can simply negate id3 in the comparison logic.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Yes.

Answer (score 1):

[The fiddle (updated)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2469f8e5be4e05db9c71f91f9115b64b)

Note: The first query requires MySQL 8.0 or better.  For older versions, a slightly different solution is required.  See the second query to support older versions too.

I believe your expected result is wrong, in that when id1, id2 are the same for empId = 3, **101 is the MIN id3 value**, not 102.  The following should do what you asked, however, using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

For each empId, assign a row number for each row based on (id1, id2, id3) being the least weighted tuple, from left to right, then choose just the first row number (`rn = 1`) in each partition.

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId ORDER BY id1, id2, id3) AS rn
          FROM EMPLOYEE
     )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
;
```

For older versions too (this doesn't produce an `rn` column in the result):

```
SELECT e1.*
  FROM      EMPLOYEE AS e1
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS e2
    ON e1.empId = e2.empId
   AND (e1.id1, e1.id2, e1.id3) > (e2.id1, e2.id2, e2.id3)
 WHERE e2.empId IS NULL
;
```

The result:

| empId | id1 | id2 | id3 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 12 | 101 | 1 |

If we want the MAX id3 (instead of MIN), for those matching cases, simply reverse the id3 logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId ORDER BY id1, id2, id3 DESC) AS rn
          FROM EMPLOYEE
     )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
;

-- and

SELECT e1.*
  FROM      EMPLOYEE AS e1
  LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS e2
    ON e1.empId = e2.empId
   AND (e1.id1, e1.id2, -e1.id3) > (e2.id1, e2.id2, -e2.id3)
 WHERE e2.empId IS NULL
;
```

The result:

| empId | id1 | id2 | id3 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 12 | 102 | 1 |